# x-editable and bootstrap datepicker css conflict

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I have problem with include boostrap datatime picker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and X-editable (https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)

If I include both CSS files:

```
bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css 
bootstrap-editable.css
```

bootstrap datatimepicker don't showing calendar after click, only time. But If I remove

```
bootstrap-edtiable.css
```

datatimepicker works correctly.

How to reslove conflicts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solve problem:

```
.datepicker > div {
    display: inherit;
}
```